# Get rid of division in modulo

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm writing a program, that draws horizontal stripes and blank spaces between them with the same height `44`.

So I made an inequality

$({{y}\over{44}}) \mod {2} < {1} $

The problem is I'm not allowed to use the division in this programming language.

Could you, please, help me to get rid of this division to make it giving me the same result.

Thanks in advance.

UPD: Sorry, I wasn't precise, I'm not allowed to use use even modulo, so I had to change it to this.

${{y} \over {44}} - {{{y} \over {44}} \over {2}} * 2 < 1 $

And this trick is working, because I can divide numbers by only powers of two.

UPD2: I changed the inequality to

${y} \mod {88} < {44} $

and transformed it to my case without modulo

${y} - {{y} \over {88}} * 88 < 44 $

but there is still division by number, which is not power of 2.

Comment: What are the possible values of $y$?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. $y$ would be positive.

Comment: What is the maximum value of $y$?

Comment: Possible values of $y$ are between `0` and `480`

Comment: For these values, you can safely use $y-\Big\lfloor\dfrac{2979y}{2^{18}}\Big\rfloor\cdot88$. See my answer below for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Which programming language does not have division?

Comment: @lhf: It is more likely a specific HW architecture, such as fixed-point processors (common among DSPs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $481$ possible values of $y\in[0,480]$.

So you can use a lookup table as follows:

```
LUT[481] =
{
    1,1,1,1 ... x 44 times
    0,0,0,0 ... x 44 times
    1,1,1,1 ... x 44 times
    0,0,0,0 ... x 44 times
    1,1,1,1 ... x 44 times
    0,0,0,0 ... x 44 times
    1,1,1,1 ... x 44 times
    0,0,0,0 ... x 44 times
    1,1,1,1 ... x 44 times
    0,0,0,0 ... x 44 times
    1,1,1,1 ... x 41 times
};
```

Then `LUT[y] == 1` $\iff y\bmod88<44$.

---

Alternatively, you can rely on the following fact:

$$\frac{2^{5n+3}}{88}\approx\Big[\frac{2^{5n+3}}{88}\Big]$$

Therefore:

$$y-\Big\lfloor\frac{y}{88}\Big\rfloor\cdot88 \approx y-\Big\lfloor\frac{y\cdot\Big[\frac{2^{5n+3}}{88}\Big]}{2^{5n+3}}\Big\rfloor\cdot88$$

The larger value of $n$ that you choose, the higher accuracy that you get.

In your case, $n=3$ seems to yield perfect accuracy for all $y\in[0,480]$.

For $n=3$, we get $2^{5n+3}=2^{5\cdot3+3}=2^{18}=262144$.

So we calculate manually $\Big[\frac{262144}{88}\Big]=2979$.

And then we can finally use the formula:

$$y-\Big\lfloor\frac{y\cdot2979}{262144}\Big\rfloor\cdot88$$

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Increment $y$ on every iteration; when it reaches $44$ toggle the stripe color and reset $y$ to $0$.